# Redirect with htaccess to folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the URL in the following format:

`localhost/project/index`

however index.php actually exists in `project/pages/index.php`

I figured this out by changing `httpd.conf` and adding the page `pages/index.php`

and then I rewrite with HTACCESS to remove the extension as follows..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

However, for any file other than index, it wouldn't work because apparently I'm not redirecting correctly.

For example, for `localhost/project/test` 
I actually want it to render `localhost/project/pages/test.php`

I honestly don't know what these htaccess rules do so I couldn't figure out how to change it.

Here's my project directory structure:

```
wamp/www/project/
               \____ pages/
                       \____ index.php
                       \____ test.php
               \____ js/
               \____ img/
               \____ .htaccess
```

Many questions were asked on how to remove the extension but this question is different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/pages/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]
```

Comment: it worked thanks. but now I'm having problems with including php files..
for example, in `project/pages/test.php` I'm including `php/classes/helper.php` and `php` folder is directing under `project` folder.. so i have to do `include("../php/classes/helper.php");` is there a way to fix this? i.e to include relative to the project folder?

Comment: PHP include is server side directive which is not affected by rewrite rules. You should set your include paths correctly in `ini.php` probably.